# Page fold animation in react native for flat list

Tags: react-native, animation, expo

I have a flastlist to which i feed a list of data which is being rendered by another component.

The first item will take the entire empty space available on the screen. And when ever the user swipe up. The page should fold from middle and display the net

```
// NewsListScreen.js
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity, FlatList } from "react-native";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import BottomTabNavigation from "../components/BottomTabNavigation";
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import SideBar from "../components/SideBar";
import axios from "axios";
import NewsItem from "../components/NewsItem";
import { PanGestureHandler, State } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import Animated from "react-native-reanimated";

const NewsListScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const viewShotRef = useRef();
  const [news, setNews] = useState(null);

  const translateY = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

  const onGestureEvent = Animated.event(
    [{ nativeEvent: { translationY: translateY } }],
    { useNativeDriver: false }
  );

  const onGestureStateChange = (event) => {
    console.log('aas')
    if (event.nativeEvent.state === State.END) {
      const threshold = Dimensions.get("window").height * 0.3;
      if (
        event.nativeEvent.translationY > threshold &&
        currentIndex < news.length - 1
      ) {
        setCurrentIndex((prevIndex) => prevIndex + 1);
      } else if (
        event.nativeEvent.translationY < -threshold &&
        currentIndex > 0
      ) {
        setCurrentIndex((prevIndex) => prevIndex - 1);
      }
      Animated.spring(translateY, {
        toValue: 0,
        useNativeDriver: false,
      }).start();
    }
  };

  const getNews = () => {
    axios
      .get(
        api_url
      )
      .then((res) => {
        setNews(res.data.response.data.news);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getNews();
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <SideBar navigation={navigation} />
      <View style={styles.tabs}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.tabItem}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 18 }}>News</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.tabItem}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 18 }}>Viral</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.tabItem}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 18 }}>Hyderabad</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
     {news && <FlatList
        data={news}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <NewsItem
            item={item}
            index={index}
            currentIndex={currentIndex}
            totalItems={news.length}
            onGestureEvent={onGestureEvent}
            onGestureStateChange={onGestureStateChange}
            translateY={translateY}
          />
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
        pagingEnabled
        scrollEnabled={false}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      />}
      <BottomTabNavigation viewShotRef={viewShotRef} navigation={navigation} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default NewsListScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: "relative",
    flex: 1,
  },
  newsContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    // position: "relative",
  },
  thumbnail: {
    resizeMode: "cover",
    height: 300,
  },
  textContainer: {
    padding: 10,
  },
  tabs: {
    marginTop: 30,
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
  },
  tabItem: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 10,
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});


import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import {
  GestureHandlerRootView,
  PanGestureHandler,
  State,
} from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import Animated, {
  useAnimatedGestureHandler,
  useAnimatedStyle,
  withSpring,
} from "react-native-reanimated";

const NewsItem = ({
  item,
  index,
  totalItems,
  onGestureEvent,
  onGestureStateChange,
  translateY,
  currentIndex,
}) => {
  const itemHeight = 600; // Adjust this based on your design
  console.log("test");
  console.log(translateY);
  const gestureHandler = useAnimatedGestureHandler({
    onStart: () => {
      translateY.value = 0;
    },
    onActive: (event) => {
      console.log('event')
      console.log(event.translationY)
      translateY.value = event.translationY;
    },
    onEnd: () => {
      if (Math.abs(translateY.value) > itemHeight * 0.3) {
        if (translateY.value > 0 && index < totalItems - 1) {
          translateY.value = withSpring(itemHeight);
        } else if (translateY.value < 0 && index > 0) {
          translateY.value = withSpring(-itemHeight);
        } else {
          translateY.value = withSpring(0);
        }
      } else {
        translateY.value = withSpring(0);
      }
    },
  });


  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("gesture");
    console.log(translateY.value);
  });

  const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      transform: [{ translateY: translateY.value }],
    };
  });

  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView>
      <PanGestureHandler
        onGestureEvent={onGestureEvent}
        onHandlerStateChange={onGestureStateChange}
      >
        <Animated.View
          style={[
            styles.newsItemContainer,
            animatedStyle,
            { height: itemHeight },
          ]}
        >
          {/* Your news item content here */}
          <Text style={styles.newsItemTitle}>{item.short_desc}</Text>
          {/* Other content */}
        </Animated.View>
      </PanGestureHandler>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  newsItemContainer: {
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    marginVertical: 10,
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 8,
    elevation: 4,
  },
  newsItemTitle: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  // Other styles as needed
});

export default NewsItem;
```

There seems to be some problems some how the swipe is not working and the page is not moving.
Please help me solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

See `onGestureStateChange()` is not being called by the user swipes.
The reason is `onGestureStateChange()` only called when the gesture handlers state changes. So gesture handlers state not changing while `onActive()` is setting `translateY.value` property directly.

You need to move `onActive()` inside `onGestureStateChange()` instead. This will ensure `translateY.value` property will only set when gesture handlers state changes.

Here you go:

```js
const NewsItem = ({
  item,
  index,
  totalItems,
  onGestureEvent,
  onGestureStateChange,
  translateY,
  currentIndex,
}) => {
  const itemHeight = 600; // Adjust this based on your design
  console.log("test");
  console.log(translateY);
  const gestureHandler = useAnimatedGestureHandler({
    onStart: () => {
      translateY.value = 0;
    },
    onActive: (event) => {
      console.log('event')
      console.log(event.translationY)
      translateY.value = event.translationY;
    },
    onEnd: () => {
      if (Math.abs(translateY.value) > itemHeight * 0.3) {
        if (translateY.value > 0 && index < totalItems - 1) {
          translateY.value = withSpring(itemHeight);
        } else if (translateY.value < 0 && index > 0) {
          translateY.value = withSpring(-itemHeight);
        } else {
          translateY.value = withSpring(0);
        }
      } else {
        translateY.value = withSpring(0);
      }
    },
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("gesture");
    console.log(translateY.value);
  });

  const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      transform: [{ translateY: translateY.value }],
    };
  });

  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView>
      <PanGestureHandler
        onGestureEvent={onGestureEvent}
        onHandlerStateChange={(event) => {
          onGestureStateChange(event);
          translateY.value = event.translationY;
        }}
      >
        <Animated.View
          style={[
            styles.newsItemContainer,
            animatedStyle,
            { height: itemHeight },
          ]}
        >
          {/* Your news item content here */}
          <Text style={styles.newsItemTitle}>{item.short_desc}</Text>
          {/* Other content */}
        </Animated.View>
      </PanGestureHandler>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
};
```